# There is no argument given that corresponds to the require formal parameter (opening form from a form)

Tags: c#

I've been trying to move code to a separate class and have changed the following:

```
public partial class Questionnaire : Form
{

    public Questionnaire()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
```

to

```
private readonly GetComponentSQL _getComponentSQL;

public Questionnaire(GetComponentSQL argGetComponentSQL)
{
    _getComponentSQL = argGetComponentSQL;

    InitializeComponent();            
}
```

Form1 contains button1 which opens Questionnaire.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Questionnaire q1 = new Questionnaire();
    q1.ShowDialog(); // Shows GPU_Suggestion
}
```

Regarding the Questionnaire q1 = newQuestionnaire();

The following error message shows - There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'argGetComponentSQL' of 'Questionnaire.Questionnaire(GetComponentSQL)'

I have changed button1_Click to:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Questionnaire q1 = new Questionnaire(GetComponentSQL argGetComponentSQL);
    q1.ShowDialog(); // Shows GPU_Suggestion
}
```

but then get the following 3 error messages:

> Syntax error, ',' expected
>
> 'GetComponentSQL' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
>
> The name 'argGetComponentSQL' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing?
If you want to open a form using a button is this:

```
Form2 questionnaire = new Form2();
questionnaire.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
Questionnaire q1 = new Questionnaire(GetComponentSQL argGetComponentSQL);
```

you are attempting to declare a new variable of type GetComponentSQL named argGetComponentSQL. That won't work in the context of passing an argument to a constructor (or any other method or function). Instead you must declare the variable on a line preceding the instantiation of the new Questionnaire, and then initialize it before passing it as an argument to the constructor.